# What is the operation when vector is indexed (without &)

Tags: rust

As per rust book (vectors section - Ch-8.1)

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let first = &v[0]; // <-- This is an immutable borrow
v.push(6); // Which is why push() operation is not allowed (since this is a mutable borrow)
println!("The first element is: {}", first);
```

Because `&v[0]` is an immutable borrow, `v.push(100)` operation should not work. Which makes sense.

However, this works:

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let first = v[0];
v.push(6);
println!("The first element is: {}", first);
```

When `&` is removed from `v[0]`, `push()` operation works fine.

Question(s):

1. If adding `&` creates a reference (and does not move ownership), does this mean after removing `&`, the ownership of `v[0]` is moved to variable `first`? If so, I am able to access `v[0]` afterwards. Why is that?
2. If (1) is not the case, is this a `Copy` operation? i.e value stored at memory location `v[0]` is copied to variable `first`?
3. If not (2), what exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is a copy, since without `&` it's moving and moving `i32` is copying it since it implements the `Copy` trait (moreover, you cannot move out of an index, so this must be a copy).

**Edit:** As suggested by @prog-fh in the comment, if you use a non-`Copy` type the compiler will tell you that:

```rust
struct NoCopy;
let mut v = vec![NoCopy];
let _first = v[0];
```

```rust
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<NoCopy>`
 --> src/main.rs:4:18
  |
4 |     let _first = v[0];
  |                  ^^^^
  |                  |
  |                  move occurs because value has type `NoCopy`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |                  help: consider borrowing here: `&v[0]`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=77f5cd40b24a4b904f6fff550dc9f7ff).

Comment: Ah! Only if I had tried the same with `String` or `struct` vector! Thanks! This helped.